# Set machine name for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to set the machine name for containers run using `docker-compose`?

I'd need to start N containers which should have a predictable machine name (Windows containers running under Windows Server 2016):

- MyName1
- MyName2
- ...
- MyNameN

This is required to test a system with many clients. Is maybe manually running the containers (`docker-run`) through a script an alternative solution? Anyway, the question is still `how can I manually set the machine name (if it is possible)`

Comment: What do you mean by "machine name": container name ?

Comment: I mean the value that's contained in the Windows environment variable "ComputerName". I'm not sure about which value from the container is mapped to that variable

Comment: Ok I understand. What is the current `ComputerName`when you run your docker compose file?

Comment: How does `ComputerName` map to `docker inspect containerName` output?

Comment: It's a unique ID which seems a hash value

Comment: Ok this is the unique id of your container. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your Windows container uses the container id as hostname.

You can define the machine hostname by adding `hostname` docker parameter.

Inside your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu
    hostname: MyName
```

This is also working with Docker run command:

```
docker run -it --hostname MyName ubuntu /bin/bash
```

To have a unique hostname for each machine you have to define multiple docker-compose files or multiple services inside a unique docker compose. You can also loop with the run command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   docker run -d --hostname test$i ubuntu
done
```